# Syntax error when running make to install WiFi drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 18.10, tp-link

I have a TP Link WN823N (Version 3.0) USB WiFi adapter. Ubuntu 18.10 lets me attempt to connect to a wireless network but fails every time with the notification:

> Connection Failed
>
> Activation of Network Connection Failed

and in dmesg

```
[ 6770.498033] wlx503eaa7e72d9: authenticate with 54:65:de:da:ec:a0
[ 6770.502236] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 6770.705027] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 6770.913021] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 3/3)
[ 6771.117055] wlx503eaa7e72d9: authentication with 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 timed out
[ 6782.213576] wlx503eaa7e72d9: authenticate with 54:65:de:da:ec:a0
[ 6782.221423] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 1/3)
[ 6782.425047] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 2/3)
[ 6782.628922] wlx503eaa7e72d9: send auth to 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 (try 3/3)
[ 6782.833127] wlx503eaa7e72d9: authentication with 54:65:de:da:ec:a0 timed out
[ 6796.212605] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaa7e72d9: link is not ready
```

So I thought it might be a driver problem. I downloaded the official driver from [their website](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver) and extracted it. Then I cd'd into the directory and ran

```
sudo make
```

and entered my password. It fails with this message:

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-11- 
generic/build M=/home/isaac/Downloads/TL- 
WN823N(US)_V3_160315_Linux/Driver  modules
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [Makefile:1696: modules] Error 2
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are the drivers just messed up? Is this not related to the drivers? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the issue is the unescaped parentheses `(US)` in the name of the working directory? What driver file *exactly* did you download from the linked site and how did you unpack it?

Comment: Okay, I renamed it and it did get further but now it has several other errors including "void value not ignored" in the line #define _seqdump seq_printf. and "timer has no member named data" Also, I downloaded the non-beta driver TL-WN823N(US)_V3_160315_Linux
and extracted it with the GUI.

Comment: At the download site, it clearly says: "For Linux kernel 2.6.24 ~ 4.9.60." You are running 4.18. This old file is incompatible with your kernel. Let's take a look at: `lsusb` and we'll troubleshoot.

Comment: with it plugged in:                                                                                                  `Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: and without it:                                                                                                               `Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
So it appears unnamed

Comment: There appears to be no difference whatever. Are there any clues when you unplug it, run: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and then insert it? Get out of 'tail' with Ctrl+c. Also, may I see: `lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how this happened. I unplugged a flash drive before running lsusb, and then afterwards tried to connect so I could show a friend the issue. Even though all I did was eject a usb drive and then try again, somehow the wifi adapter is working now. Anyone know why this happened? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't any idea at all. Glad it's working in any case.